# How to deactivate the creation of a service while importing WSDL in WSO2 GREG?

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

Is there anyway to deactivate the automatic generation of a service while importing a WSDL in WSO2 GREG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment following entry in GREG_HOME/repositroy/conf/registry.xml

```
  <property name="createService">false</property>
```

Comment: A clarification. This property is configured per handler, so using the default handlers you have it in both '<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.ZipWSDLMediaTypeHandler">' and '<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions.handlers.WSDLMediaTypeHandler">'

Comment: Yes. Those are two ways you can upload wsdls. One is as a single file. So it will hit WSDLMediaTypeHandler or as an archive so it will hit ZipWSDLMediaTypeHandler. so you need to uncomment in both if you use them.